# Why are store bought paninis only par baked?

Tags: baking, bread

I bought some mini paninis from the super market and the packet had instructions to bake them again for another 5-6 minutes before serving. Why are paninis sold par baked and not completely baked like other bread?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parbaking) does a nice job of explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convenience and longer term storage, plus a closer to freshly baked result compared to a pre baked item that has or is going stale to some degree,